# Página cargada completamente en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como puedo hacer lo siguiente.

Recibo un de una web api un json que son elementos que a su vez tiene un json que son imágenes.

A estos arrays los recorrido con `ng-repeat` y imprimó en la vista las imágenes. Luego al `div` que contiene estas imágenes necesito aplicar una función que lo "convierte" en carousel  de imágenes.

El problema que al momento de aplicar esta función el `ng-repeat` no finalizó, entonces no funciona.

Necesito entonces ejecutar una función JavaScript que se ejecute al finalizar el `ng-repeat` o algún método en angularjs al estilo de `$(document).ready` de jQuery.

En el controller tengo

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    for (var c = 0; c < $scope.listadoCampanias.Promociones.length; c++) {


        $("#slideshow-" + $scope.listadoCampanias[0].Promociones[c].IdPromocion+" > div:gt(0)").hide();
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#slideshow-' + $scope.listadoCampanias[0].Promociones[c].IdPromocion + ' > div:first')
                .css("display", "none")
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow-' + $scope.listadoCampanias[0].Promociones[c].IdPromocion);
        }, 3000);



    }
});
```

En la vista solo recorro $scope.listadoCampanias[0].Promociones
eh imprimo las imagenes

Comment: Creo que deberías leer sobre ésto: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks puede ser que te sirva ngAfterViewChecked(). Saludos!.

Comment: Lucho pregunta por AngularJS no Angular

Answer (score 1):

Coloca el código que corresponde al carrusel en una directiva y utiliza la función `link` para manipular los elementos del DOM. En este caso para crear el carousel en este momento luego que ya se ejecutó el `ng-repeat`

Más información en [Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom)

Answer (score -1):

[angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

```
<script>
  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
     //pon tu codigo aqui, se ejectuara despues de que el controlador
     //este cargado
     alert('angular work is done. run javascript');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Eso en la vista no funciona porque necesito recrrer un array que esta en el scope ($scope.listaElementos)
Y en el controller me dice que $scope.listaElementos es undefined, como si el array todavia no se generó pareciera, pero deberia porque lo ejecuto dentro del ready...